# Koa Auth flow with compose

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, koa

I have this isAuthenticated function in expressjs.  Basically it is just a function that composes express middleware into one middleware.  Since now I want to migrate from express to koa, how do I do the same thing in koa?

```
import compose from 'composable-middleware';

export function isAuthenticated() {
  return compose()
   // Validate JWT
   .use(function(req, res, next) {
      if (req.query && req.query.hasOwnProperty('access_token')) {
          req.headers.authorization = 'Bearer ' + req.query.access_token;
      }
      validateJwt(req, res, next);
   })
  // Attach user to request
  .use(function(req, res, next) {
     User.findByIdAsync(req.user._id)
       .then(user => {
          if (!user) {
           return res.status(401).end();
          }
          req.user = user;
        next();
       })
       .catch(err => next(err));
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question here, turns out not that hard

```
import compose from 'koa-compose';
import convert from 'koa-convert';
import User from '../api/user/user.model';

const validateJwt = convert(koaJwt({
 secret: config.secrets_session
}));

 /**
 * Attaches the user object to the request if authenticated
 * Otherwise returns 403
 */
 export function isAuthenticated() {
   function authentication(ctx, next) {
     // allow access_token to be passed through query parameter as well
    if (ctx.query && ctx.query.hasOwnProperty('access_token')) {
      ctx.headers.authorization = `Bearer ${ctx.query.access_token}`;
    }

   validateJwt(ctx, next);
  }

  function attachUserToContext(ctx, next) {
     User.findById(ctx.state.user._id)
      .then(user => {
        if (!user) {
           return ctx.status = 401;
        }

         ctx.state.user = user;

        next();
     })
     .catch(err => next(err));
  }

  return compose([authentication, attachUserToContext]);
 }
```